# shellscript: not able to assign integer to a variable

Tags: shell, scripting

For follwoing script

```
#!/bin/sh

    count1=0
    noOfArg=0
    checkOtherParam()
    {
    echo $parameter
    return 4
    }
    if($count1 eq $noOfArg)
    then
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "No

"
fi
```

~
I am getting error

./sample.sh: 0: not found
No

please let me know, what is the problem

Answer (score 3):

I would write the comparison like this

```
if (($count1 == $noOfArg))
then
...
fi
```

The above is an arithmetic comparison, as opposed to the conditional comparison performed by

```
if [ $count1 -eq $noOfArg ]
then
...
fi
```

However in this case I'm assuming they would both produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

It's your use of parenthesis in the if statement. That's not proper bash syntax. Here it is corrected (sans the mysterious broken checkOtherParam function):

```
#!/bin/sh

count1=0
noOfArg=0

if [ $count1 -eq $noOfArg ]
then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($count1 eq $noOfArg)
```

should be

```
if [ $count1 -eq $noOfArg ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `case/esac`

```
case "$count" in
 "$noOfArg" ) echo "yes";;
 *) echo "no";;
esac
```